# Como colocar un grupo de controles dentro de un marco. Añadir borde a Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quisiera saber como le hago para colocar, por ejemplo, **un grupo de label y/o Entry** que **queden (visualmente hablando) dentro de un marco** que rodee dichos controles y que **ese marco sea visible**. Yo estoy usando tkinter en python pero no se como hacerlo.

Yo uso `Frame` con el parámetro `bd=2`, pero no se dibuja nada. Espero haberme hecho explicar.

Lo que busco es que haya (por ejemplo) una sección de "datos personales", y otra sección de "datos laborales" (si fuera el caso), pero sin que estos se vean como que todos en la misma sección. Esto por poner un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Lo que deseas es un frame en tu ventana principal que contenga dos label dentro del mismo ?
Si es asi, talvez estes buscando esto:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('HOLA')

Frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=400, bg='gray19')
Frame.place(x=155, y=5)

label1 =tk.Label(Frame, bg='gray99', borderwidth=1, relief='solid', width=42, 
height=10)
label1.place(x=5, y=20)

label2 =tk.Label(Frame, bg='gray99', borderwidth=1, relief='solid', width=42, 
height=10)
label2.place(x=5, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, tambien me sirve. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres agregar un marco sólido al frame del color que desees, puedes usar `highlightbackground`, `highlightcolor`, `highlightthickness` (para controlar el grosor).

Además tienes la opción de añadir un borde decorado mediante `relief`, cuyo grosor se controla con `bd`/`borderwidth`. En tu caso no se muestra nada porque por defecto `relief` es `flat`, solo se muestraa un frame un poco más grande, con un borde del mismo color que el fondo.

Un pequeño muestrario:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

frame1 = tk.Frame(
    root, highlightbackground="#8258FA",
    highlightcolor="#8258FA", highlightthickness=4,
    relief=tk.FLAT, bd=20,
    background="#CEF6E3"
    )

tk.Label(frame1, text="FLAT", font=30, bg="#CEF6E3").pack(expand=True)
frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both",padx=20, pady=10)

frame2 =tk.Frame(
    root, highlightbackground="#8258FA",
    highlightcolor="#8258FA", highlightthickness=4,
    relief=tk.SUNKEN, bd=20,
    background="#CEF6E3"
    )
tk.Label(frame2, text="SUNKEN", font=30, bg="#CEF6E3").pack(expand=True)
frame2.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=10)

frame3 =tk.Frame(
    root, highlightbackground="#8258FA",
    highlightcolor="#8258FA", highlightthickness=4,
    relief=tk.RAISED, bd=20,
    background="#CEF6E3"
    )
tk.Label(frame3, text="RAISED", font=30, bg="#CEF6E3").pack(expand=True)
frame3.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=10)

frame4 =tk.Frame(
    root, highlightbackground="#8258FA",
    highlightcolor="#8258FA", highlightthickness=4,
    relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=20,
    background="#CEF6E3"
    )
tk.Label(frame4, text="GROOVE", font=30, bg="#CEF6E3").pack(expand=True)
frame4.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=10)

frame5 =tk.Frame(
    root, highlightbackground="#8258FA",
    highlightcolor="#8258FA", highlightthickness=4,
    relief=tk.RIDGE, bd=20,
    background="#CEF6E3"
    )
tk.Label(frame5, text="RIDGE", font=30, bg="#CEF6E3").pack(expand=True)
frame5.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Para agrandar hacer click en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo, eso me sirve. Muy amable.